# Automator rename finder item date and time

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I want to use automator to create a project folder with a Automator service, but i like to add the month and year (with two decimals) not the day, month and whole year.

want i can creatie is item_29022014 but i like to create a file named: 'item_0214' where the first two numbers (02) are the month and the last two numbers (14) are the last to numbers of the current year(2014).

Can i download some add-on for automator? Or do i need a custom script for this?

[image]

Comment: I am confused, try again. Is that a part of file name?

Comment: i cant explain my self better then this.

Comment: great job, it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer found here

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52535/clean-up-file-names-using-automator

I changed the bash script code to include the date code.

```
shopt -s extglob
dcode=`date '+%m%y'`
for f in "$@"; do
   f1="${f%.*}"
   f2="${f##*.}"
   if [ "$f2" == "$f1" ] ; then     
       echo "$f" "${f1}_${dcode}"
   else
       echo "$f" "${f1}_${dcode}.${f2}"
   fi
done
```

The code will should work even with files that do not have extensions.

Replace the commands echo with mv to actually get the code to do anything.

Hope that helped.